# fill_between of pandas Dataframe (values) by column

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to plot fill_between automatically by pandas or numpy column for each existing column, as is it with basic plot?
I don't want to repeat the fill_between command for each column.

e.g.:

```
x = np.array([np.arange(4), np.arange(4)]).transpose()
y = np.zeros((4,2))
y[:,1] = 1
yerr=np.zeros((4,2))
yerr[:,0] = 0.1
yerr[:,1] = 0.2

plt.plot(x,y)
```

And then I would like to do something like this (not per column)

```
plt.fill_between(x,y-yerr,y+yerr)
```

but I get:

> ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible

UPDATE: 
Ok, I remembered I can do list comprehension:

```
[plt.fill_between(x[:,i],(y-yerr)[:,i],(y+yerr)[:,i]
                  for i in np.arange(y.shape[1])]
```

So the question would have to be: is there no internal way for fill_between to do this?

Comment: The purpose of a comprehension is to create a value. If you are throwing the value away that's a code smell indicating that a `for` loop is probably better.

Comment: I think in principle it should be possible using numpy arrays and it could be fixed in `fill_between`. So I think it is reasonable to write a feature request/bug report to github.com/matplotlib

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7355)